# WPF Window fadeIn does not work

Tags: wpf, window, fadein

I have the following code:

```
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.7" Color="White" x:Name="BackgroundBrush"></SolidColorBrush>
</Window.Background>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:5" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" From="0.7">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

But nothing happened when window is shown. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what H.B. said, you need to add your BeginStoryboard to the [EventTrigger.Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.actions.aspx) collection, not the EnterActions collection. So this works:

```
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.7" Color="White" x:Name="BackgroundBrush"></SolidColorBrush>
</Window.Background>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:5" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" From="0.7">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to animate the opacity of the window itself, rather than the background.
2. You need to set [`AllowsTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) to `true`, which also necessitates the [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) to be set to `None`. (You need to create your own standard window buttons)

Comment: AllowsTransparency is true, WindowStyle is None but even this code:     <Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="MWindow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style> does not work